# Bluemix Watson IoT Blockchain multiple invocations in 1 block

Tags: ibm-cloud, blockchain, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric, watson-iot

I'm following [this tutorial](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/IoT/blockchain/dev_blockchain.html) to connect up Watson IoT with Blockchain.

I set up node-red & Watson IoT Platform with Blockchain extension enabled & connected. I set up the fabric, and everything seems to be working. However, my IoT device sent 3 messages of the same payload thru.

When I look at the block activity, I see 1 block with 3 invocations instead of 3 blocks with 1 invocation each.

Why is there only 1 block versus 3 blocks?

[image: Block activity]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of transactions (deploy or invoke) per block depends on timing.  Since the IoT device sent three messages with the same payload, I would image that this happened in close time proximity.  A block is created every second or when 1,000 transactions have been added to a block (whichever comes first).  If the three invocations happened in less than the span of a second, then they would be included in the same block.

Comment: thank you for the info! also, would you happen to know why there's an "x" in the payload before the json data?

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not sure exactly what is causing the “x” in the payload.  This could depend on how the chaincode is implemented.  I imagine that “updateAsset” is a method in the chaincode.  Perhaps “x” is an identifier for the entity being updated based on the JSON contents.

Comment: the chaincode is this sample code: https://github.com/ibm-watson-iot/blockchain-samples/blob/master/contracts/basic/simple_contract/simple_contract_hyperledger.go#L323

Comment: The display of payload on the "Blockchain” tab of the Bluemix dashboard includes the function called and the arguments passed.  For example, in the case of [Example02] (https://github.com/IBM-Blockchain/example02) you would see a payload like `invoke a b 10`.  In your case, the “updateAsset” function is noted, followed by the arguments 'x' and then the JSON structure.  To write the new state to the ledger, the `stub.PutState(assetID, stateJSON)` statement is included in the “createOrUpdateAsset” function (called from “updateAsset”).  I believe that 'x' corresponds to the “assetID”.